# Three.js: Converting RGB Decimal color into HEX RGB color

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, hex, rgb

Hello right now I have a task to do but I am kind of stuck with the color bit. I am working with three.js (a javascript library). In the task at a certain point, I need to convert decimal color code (e.g `12615680` into something like this: `#FF0000` or `0xFF0000`. The solution should be javascript code (function) which can convert the decimal color to hex.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hex-to-rgba

Comment: Well, I have made few function trying to convert RGB into hex but the thing is I am not sure what I am doing wrong and if this is even the possible solution, that's why I am here

Comment: So the number `12615680` corresponds to `C08000` in hex, is that the color you want from that input?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work that's the problem, please look at the example above and try getting a color using that, if it works please submit your code!

Comment: Yes that is the color I want :D

Comment: Problem is I can't make it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In three.js, you can use this pattern to convert a decimal color to a hex string:

```
var c = new THREE.Color(); // create once and reuse

c.set( 12615680 );

c.getHexString(); // "c08000"
```

three.js r.89

Comment: Please finish it off. var example = c.getHexString(); or like how do I get the value so I can put it in the parameters of the sphere?

Comment: There is no 'sphere' in your question. Please do not modify your question after is has been answered. Instead, make a new post and include the code you need help with.

Comment: THREE.Color: Unknown color 0xc08000

Comment: This is the error I get if I use your method I get the same but like this: THREE.Color: Unknown color c08000

Comment: From your profile, you appear to be a beginner. Consider posting your questions on https://discourse.threejs.org. It may be a more beginner-friendly site. Always show your code when you post a question.

Comment: I found the solution my self. Yes, I am a beginner but only to the library. I am not that bad at js, html, and css brother :D

Comment: Solution was: after using your, my or any other solution to simply convert the string I get a result into a number which I did like this: Number(stringVar);